# Garbage Disposal Not Working - No power From Cable

Tags: garbage-disposal

My garbage disposal stopped working out of the blue today. I did all the usual troubleshooting: nothing appears to be stuck in it. I tried rotating it with an allen wrench from beneath the unit, and also tried the reset switch on it. None of my breakers were tripped, none of the GFCI outlets in the kitchen or anywhere in the house are tripped.

The outlet which has the switch for the disposal is also where our coffee maker is plugged in, as well as an overhead light, and both work. I bought a non-contact voltage meter, and it seems the wire running to the disposal doesn't have any power going to it even when I flip the disposal on.

The dishwasher and disposal are both on the same breaker, and the dishwasher works fine. The disposal is hardwired but the wire seems to go out of the cabinet and into the wall somewhere. If power isnt running through this cable, is it still more likely that the motor is just dead, or should I call an electrician to look at the wiring?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check that your new non-contact tester actually works (and that you're using it correctly) by testing another known-hot cable?

Comment: Yes, I tested a lamp in another room when it was on and off, and it only went off when I touched it to the lamp's cord when the lamp was on. I also used it to test the other two cables going into an electrical box under the sink. One of those I assume is the dishwasher, and both lit up.

Comment: Is the unit hardwired or is it on a cordset? Mine are on cordsets so I simply unplug, plug in a light and I know if power is there or not.

Comment: @gil I think it's hardwired completely. What's confusing is that the cable seems to follow the sewer pipe into the wall so I'm not sure where it goes. I'm pretty much assuming I'll have to call an electrician, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some possibility of it still being a dead motor in the disposal so I could just replace it instead.

Comment: Have you checked power at the switch that turns it on?

Comment: It sounds like the switch is broken.  Is it an air switch? Wall switch? Magnetic?  Can you test it directly?  Check the live and switched terminals with the switch off and on.

Comment: @jay613 It's a regular wall switch. There are 2 switches and 2 GFIC plugs all in the same box. Both of the plugs work fine, and the other switch controls the overhead light which also works fine. I assume I will need to take the switch cover off for the tester to get close enough. I didn't think to do that yet, but I will tomorrow morning, thanks!

Comment: Also check the GFCI test and reset buttons.  Could be a ground fault or failed GFCI.

Comment: Were you able to rotate the disposal using the allen wrench from below?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica yes, without issue. I'll take apart the wall switch cover today and check to see if anything is loose there.